# override a text entry from the framework in an Eclipse Scout application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-scout

I am using the [eclipse-scout](http://eclipse.org/scout/) framework.

How can I override a Text entry in my application to replace an entry provided by the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you an example coming from [Bug 431234](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431234).

[image: Eclipse Scout Field - Bug 431234]

Open the NLS Editor for your Scout Application:

- In the **Scout Explorer View** select `Scout Projects > {your app} > {app}.shared > Text Provider Services > {App}TextProviderService`.
- And then in the **Scout Object Properties View** click on the `Open NLS Editor...` link.

Add a new language with the appropriate tool button:

[image: Toolbutton 'New Language...' in the NLS Editor]

Choose the language in the dialog (Dutch in our example) and confirm with Ok:

[image: Add a Language Dialog]

You can uncheck the `Hide inherited rows` checkbox and set the key filter to `NumberToo`.

[image: NLS Editor]

Add a new entry with the `New Entry` tool button.

[image: Toolbutton 'New Entry...' in the NLS Editor]

In the Dialog prepare your new text entry:

[image: 'New Entry' Dialog]

The warning only tells you that you are overriding a text defined in Scout RT. You click on the save button to close dialog. (More information in [Bug 439590](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439590)).

The NLS Editor should display your version of the text.

When you start your application with the appropriate language, you should see the difference:

[image: Eclipse Scout Field]